# Searching for both ends of range from pandas data frame in another data frame and expanding it to a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Pandas and Python as well. I have 2 data frames created from importing 2 tables from mysql database :

1. Ranges
2. titles

`ranges` data frame :

```
title s_low s_high post pre noy
1       104  106b   0   2   0
1       1     5     1   0   0
```

Here, each row represents a range of sections with the last three columns having data related to the sections in the range. s_low represents the lower end section of a range and s_high represents the higher end section. There are tens of titles, and each title has many sections.

`titles` data frame: (it contains all the data relating to all the sections under all the titles.

```
title   section
1   1
1   101
1   102
1   103
1   104
1   105
1   106
1   106a
1   106b
1   107
1   108
1   109
1   110
1   111
1   112
1   112a
1   112b
1   113
1   114
1   2
1   201
1   202
1   203
1   204
1   205
1   206
1   207
1   208
1   209
1   210
1   211
1   212
1   213
1   3
1   4
1   5
1   6
1   7
1   8
```

I have to expand the ranges in the `ranges` and write the section in between each range to a new data frame along with the values in the last three columns : post, pre and noy.

Here's the code I've generated so far.

```
import MySQLdb as db
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas.io.sql import frame_query
import pandas as pd

cnxn = db.connect('xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx', charset='utf8', use_unicode=True )
ranges = frame_query("SELECT * from ranges", cnxn)
titles = frame_query("SELECT title, section from titles", cnxn)

exp = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['title', 'section', 'post', 'pre', 'noy'])

for index, row in ranges.iterrows():
    t = row['title']
    s_low = row['s_low']
    s_low1 = str(t)+'$'+s_low
    s_high = row['s_high']
    s_high1 = str(t)+'$'+s_high
    post = row['post']
    pre = row['pre']
    noy = row['noy']
    x=0
    for i, r in titles.iterrows():
        title = r['title']
        sec = r['section']
        if ((str(t)+'$'+s_low) == (str(title)+'$'+sec)):
            x = <index of sec>
```

I am using string concatenate because there are multiple titles and multiple sections; same section code can be present under a different title. 
I understand that I need to loop through the index of titles after finding the s_low until I reach s_high and write the values to the new data frame exp. I'm not able to get the index of s_low to proceed further.

Sample output (exp data frame) for the first row in ranges sample pasted above would be :

```
title section post pre noy
1      104     0    2   0
1      105     0    2   0
1      106     0    2   0
1      106a    0    2   0
1      106b    0    2   0
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.