# Selecting all the rows between 2 specific rows in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data frames, first one with 5 columns that defines the search criteria and second with 2 columns which is the data that's searched.

I need to write all the rows between 2 rows that match a certain criteria from the second data frame to a new data frame.

There are thousands of such cases (one per each row from first data frame) to be written.

Can I use any() or isin() here so that I could retireve the index of the 2 rows that match the criteria and loop in between to write the target rows to a new data frame one by one?

This question is related to my previous question which was never answered. 
([Searching for both ends of range from pandas data frame in another data frame and expanding it to a new data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162379/searching-for-both-ends-of-range-from-pandas-data-frame-in-another-data-frame-an))
I've figured out a little bit of the solution for it and am posting this question to move forward.

Comment: I don't understand your criteria for selection but you can use boolean condition to select the rows of interest and then access the index values to determine the start and end points e.g. `df[df['col'] > myVal].index.min()` (or max()) you can then use this to perform slicing, you'd need to post your specific requirements as it is possible that this can be heavily optimised without iterating over all the rows

Comment: Thanks for the response @EdChum. I will look into the method that you have suggested. I've just added the link to my previous question that has the full description of the exact problem I'm trying to solve, if it helps.